# Rails 3.1 mailer pdf attachment damaged

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is my mailer:

```
class MailIt < ActionMailer::Base

    def funny(sender)
        @sender = sender
        attachments['funny.pdf'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/funny.pdf")
        mail(:to => "amail@example.com",
             :from => "amail@example.com",
             :subject => "TESST")
    end

end
```

I get the e-mail with the attached pdf but it is damaged and the file size is only 1/4 of the original file.

Comment: yes windows. It seems like it is an encoding problem maybe...

Comment: that I supposed, because I am using this exact same code in UNIX without problems. Encoding, binary mode issues, who knows...

Answer (score 2):

if you have images in your pdf, you have to send it as binary.

```
attachments['funny.pdf'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/funny.pdf", :mode => 'rb')
```

Comment: Thank you - this is very important and not mentioned in the guidelines for action mailer at all, but a key problem many will face.

Answer (score 1):

I did find a solution.

It seems like there is a problem with File.read

I tried this and it worked:

```
attachments['funny.pdf'] = File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/funny.pdf").read
```

Comment: Now there is a problem with images -.-